# Red5 Client in Java for Applet or Android

Tags: java, android, applet, video-streaming, red5

Is there anyone who has experience in developing a java client for red5?
Its so simple in flash/flex but in java it seems to be really complicated.

I use the latest stable version 0.9.1 of the red5-server package for debian. All demo stuff works fine and I was able to create a flex client for live publishing and subscribing, too.

I was suprised that the subscriber works on my htc (Android 2.2.1) in the webbrowser, too. The broadcater doesnt :-(. I think there are some problems or restrictions with cam.

However, since flash is not longer supported on android (what a shame), i need to find other resolutions. I fear that HTML5 and Javascript is not a good choise at this time, so I think java is the best way to realise Client for broadcasting and subscribing that should work in the future. What do you think about that?

I found the http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/client/trunk/ and compiled it in eclipse. But it doesnt seem to work with red5-server 0.9.1. I got strange errors in debugger and the red5 log says:

```
[Red5_Scheduler_Worker-1] WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 192.168.1.101 : 60869 to null (in: 3073 out 3073 ), with id 10340902 due to long handshake
```

Maybe something has changed in the handshake details, the client is the latest version from SVN and designed for Version Red5 1.0 i think.

However, I struggled a lot of time with Java and now its time to ask the community. I search for the best way to create solutions for android phone and webbrowsers.

thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to Paul Gregoire's blog. He is a dev of Red5 project and he has realized some (at least proof of concept) clients that stream camera to Red5.
http://gregoire.org/2012/01/17/android-market/

You might also simply search for "RTMP Android" and you will find plenty of stuff. I don't need to copycat those links here I guess.

Sebastian

Comment: I spent a lot of time with googling for "RTMP Android" "RTMT Java" but it was a pain. I think there a different implementations of RTMP specially find something working with RED5s Version 0.9 is the challenge. Its strange cause flash itself doesnt seem to have problems with this version. The Paul Gegoire's project is nice but I would like to get sources!

Comment: you know that you can compile Adobe Air applications to native iOS apps? With those I think webcam/mic access might work.